# Auto expand some of the branches in WinEdt tree

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, winedt

My tree panel in WinEdt is like this:

[image]

I am wondering whether there is a way to expand all the packages and section branches, to avoid having to open all of the sections when looking for a specific figure?

[image]

EDIT:
@Harish Kumar - thanks for your reply, but it makes the tree look like this:
[image]

Is there anyway to make it this way with the figures not showing the includegraphics:
[image]

Comment: See Karl's comment below my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have that branch always expanded, follow the instructions in Harish Kumar's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167792/27635).

If you don't need this, you can always right-click on the branch and you'll see this popup menu:

[image]

If you click on "Expand branch" the branch will be full expanded, while if you click on "Expand All" all the branches will be full expanded.

Corresponding "Collapse" commands do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

You have to open `tree.ini`. There you will find

```
BRANCH_EXPANDED=0
```

line under `BRANCH="Packages-TeX"` and `BRANCH="TOC-TeX"` (two instances). Change both in to

```
BRANCH_EXPANDED=1
```

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F9</kbd> . Now if you build tree you should get things expanded.

[image]

Hope it is useful.

Comment: I'm seeing that you've added the branch "Packages" in your configuration. ;-)

Comment: @karlkoeller hihi, I just wanted to play with it as soon as I saw your other answer. I am very curious on every thing you know :). BTW did you see the other query of OP (as another answer)? Do you have to say anything about it? please.

Comment: There's nothing that can be done, apart from disabling collecting `\includegraphics`